# How can I use C# to search the contents of pdf's in Elastic?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, pdf

Elastic I can access with C# for simple Put, Post, Get, Delete.
Now I ingest pdf files into elastic.
I can successfully search in it with the Kibana console.
But at my C# code I don't get any search result.
I'm pretty sure the problem is in the syntax of my code.
I tried many things, but I still don't get a result.
I tried searching in the "Content" and "Attachment" fields.
How do I search an attachment with C#?

my successful request at kibana console:

```
GET /attachments/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "attachment.content": "Meeting"
    }
  }
}
```

But using C# it is unsuccessful:

```
        var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
           .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                .Field(f => f.Attachment.Content)
                .Query("Meeting")
                )
           )
        );
```

Also unsuccessful:

```
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Document>(Nest.Indices.All)
        {
            Query = new MatchQuery
            {
                Field = Infer.Field<Document>(f => f.Content),
                Query = "Meeting"
            }
        };
        var searchResponse2 = client.Search<Document>(searchRequest);
```

Also unsuccessful:

```
        var searchResponse3 = client.Search<Document>(s => s
            .Index("attachments")
            .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
            .Match(mt => mt.Field(f => f.Content).Query("Meeting"))
        ))));
```

Successful ingesting pdf files:
(I can also count the files and get the right number of 540 attachments.)

```
        var base64File = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        var indexResponse = client.Index(new Document
        {
              Id = i,
              Path = path,
              Content = base64File
        }, i => i
              .Pipeline("attachments")
              .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
        );
```

My Document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

the mapping:

```json
{
  "attachments" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "author" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "creator_tool" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "description" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "detect_language" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "format" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "indexed_chars" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "keywords" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "metadata_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "modified" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "path" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put index mapping and sample document from Elasticsearch

Comment: I've done something very similar in the past. I built an email archival system using C# and Elasticsearch. What I did, was rip the Mime out of the mail, store it and then rip all the content from the attachment, while storing the file itself in cold storage. So I had the mail contents, attachments and their contents, and the original files in cold storage. THat allowed me to do what you're looking to do

Comment: @SagarPatel I add the mapping to the initial article.

Comment: @SimonC As I read at Elastic the architecture of hot/warm/cold storage is not recommended anymore. I also couldn't figure out how it could help me with my code and the get statement.

Comment: @SimonC https://www.elastic.co/blog/implementing-hot-warm-cold-in-elasticsearch-with-index-lifecycle-management

Comment: @SimonC And as I think for my application I don't need the hot/worm/cold storage architecture for now.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.
I indexed all the contents (mime content, attachment contents) into Elastic and the files themselves into cold storage.
Using Tika for .net, I indexed all the images, PDFs and whatnot, indexed the contents. And if the file itself was required for download, it was retrieved from cold storage. The approach is much more flexible than indexing binary data into Elastic and then ripping the contents from there

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a nice solution with the ElasticClient. But I found one with the HttClient from .NET. This looks like this:
(For local Elastic, version 8.2)

```
    public async Task<JObject> GetJson(string request)
    {
        sep.Username = "elastic";
        sep.Password ="...";
        sep.Url = "https://localhost:9200/attachments/_search";
        try
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add($"Authorization", $"Basic {Base64Encode($"{sep.Username}:{sep.Password}")}");
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, sep.Url);
            message.Content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseString);
            foreach (var e in json)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string Base64Encode(string textToEncode)
    {
        byte[] textAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncode);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(textAsBytes);
    }
```

Call:

```
string jsonString = "{   \"query\": { \"match\": { \"attachment.content\": \"Meeting\" }}}";
JObject jObj = await manager.GetJson(jsonString);
```